# Java AddressBook Input Data Into A JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need some help with a project that i have been set. I am creating a small addressbook program in java. I have got the user interface sorted and i am now working on adding information into a JTable from an inputDialog.

Here is my addressbook user Interface.

```
    import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AddressBookGUI {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;
    private static JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JFrame addPersonFrame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(768, 300);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.setBounds(10, 228, 89, 23);
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Name: ");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Last Name: ");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Address: ");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Town: ");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("County: ");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Post Code: ");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Phone Number: ");

            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(addButton);

        JButton editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.setBounds(109, 228, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(editButton);

        JButton delButton = new JButton("Delete");
        delButton.setBounds(208, 228, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(delButton);
        // Declare new menuBar and menuItems
        JMenuBar mainMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenuBar = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        JMenuItem newFileMenuBar = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem openFileMenuBar = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem saveFileMenuBar = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem printFileMenuBar = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem quitFileMenuBar = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem editMenuBar = new JMenu();
        JMenuItem editPersonsEditMenuBar = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem sortNameEditMenuBar = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem sortPostcodeEditMenuBar = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem helpMenuBar = new JMenu();
        JMenuItem aboutHelpMenuBar = new JMenuItem();

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 742, 21);
        frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);
        // Declares and adds items to the menu
        JMenuItem menuItemNew = new JMenuItem("New");
        mnFile.add(menuItemNew);

        JMenuItem menuItemOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
        mnFile.add(menuItemOpen);

        JMenuItem menuItemSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
        mnFile.add(menuItemSave);

        JMenuItem menuItemSaveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As..");
        mnFile.add(menuItemSaveAs);

        JMenuItem menuItemPrint = new JMenuItem("Print");
        mnFile.add(menuItemPrint);

        JMenuItem menuItemQuit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menuItemQuit.addActionListener(new exitApp());
        mnFile.add(menuItemQuit);

        JMenu menuEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(menuEdit);

        JMenuItem menuItemEditSelectedPerson = new JMenuItem(
                "Edit Selected Person");
        menuEdit.add(menuItemEditSelectedPerson);

        JMenuItem menuItemSortByName = new JMenuItem("Sort By Name");
        menuEdit.add(menuItemSortByName);

        JMenuItem menuItemSortPostCode = new JMenuItem("Sort By Post Code");
        menuEdit.add(menuItemSortPostCode);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 32, 732, 151);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                { "", null, "", "", "", null, null },
                { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
                { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
                { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
                { null, null, null, null, null, null, null },
                { null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, }, new String[] {
                "First Name", "Last Name", "Addesss", "Town", "County",
                "Post Code", "Phone Number" }));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    static class exitApp implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // closes the application
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

}
```

If some one could help me that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry i should of made my self more clear. I do not know how to add the text that i will in put into the  'JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Name: ");' and pass it into the jtable so that the information show up in the jtable.

Comment: Are you telling _How to pass the data from the JOptionPane to JTable_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass the entered data from the `JOptionPane` to the `JTable` then first get the data and the UI and add it to the JTable.

If you are storing each row as an Object then use the [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29),

```
model.addRow(..);
```

If you are storing each value individually then use the [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29),

```
// value here is your input.
setValueAt(value, rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create some variables to save infomation you inputed.

Then use

```
table.getModel().table.getModel().setValueAt("ddd", 2, 2);
```

Pass it into the Jtable.